# How can I unwrap an optional value inside a binding in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm building an app using SwiftUI and would like a way to convert a `Binding<Value?>` to a `Binding<Value`>.

In my app I have an `AvatarView` which knows how to render an image for a particular user.

```swift
struct AvatarView: View {
  @Binding var userData: UserData

  ...
}
```

My app holds a `ContentView` that owns two bindings: a dictionary of users by id, and the id of the user whose avatar we should be showing.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var userById: Dictionary<Int, UserData>
  @State var activeUserId: Int

  var body: some View {
    AvatarView(userData: $userById[activeUserId])
  }
}
```

Problem: the above code doesn't combine because `$userById[activeUserId]` is of type `Binding<UserData?>` and `AvatarView` takes in a `Binding<UserData>`.

Things I tried...

- `$userById[activeUserId]!` doesn't work because it's trying to unwrap a `Binding<UserData?>`. You can only unwrap an `Optional`, not a `Binding<Optional>`.
- `$(userById[activeUserId]!)` doesn't work for reasons that I don't yet understand, but I think something about `$` is resolved at compile time so you can't seem to prefix arbitrary expressions with `$`.

Comment: Did you try `$userById[activeUserId] as! Binding<UserData>`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I think it would probably work fine, but I would prefer not to do an unsafe cast. When I try it I get a build warning saying "Cast from Binding<UserData?> to unrelated type Binding<UserData>"

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/3115381-init), which seems to handle this exact case - converting `Binding<T?>` to `Binding<T>?`:

```
var body: some View {
    AvatarView(userData: Binding($userById[activeUserId])!)
}
```

I have used `!` to force unwrap, just like in your attempts, but you could unwrap the `nil` however you want. The expression `Binding($userById[activeUserId])` is of type `Binding<UserData>?`.

Comment: WARNING! This will crash if the binding is later set to nil, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958106/exception-when-setting-an-optional-binding-to-nil-in-swiftui-after-checking

Comment: @Rick that's the same with any force unwrap. You just need to handle the nil case eg using an if let