# SwiftUI programmatic navigation. How to use Binding<Bool> when method expects Binding<Bool?>?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm building programmatic navigation in SwiftUI app. I want to open screens when model changes, not when user just taps on button. I want to keep my code descriptive without unnecessary optionals all over it. Problem is some SwiftUI methods expect to see `Binding<Bool?>` instead of more descriptive `Binding<Bool>`. Example:

```
class NavigationState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showNextScreen: Bool = false
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationState: NavigationState

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Show next screen",
                       destination: NextView(),
                       tag: true,
                       selection: $navigationState.showNextScreen)  // <--- Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool?>'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to build programmatic navigation **without** making ivar optionals all over the app by changing
`@Published var showNextScreen: Bool = false`
to
`@Published var showNextScreen: Bool? = false`
Because changing it to optional will make code less descriptive than it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [an initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(_:)-6krsi) that converts a `Binding<V>` to a `Binding<V?>`, so you just need to do:

```
NavigationLink("Show next screen",
               destination: NextView(),
               tag: true,
               selection: Binding($navigationState.showNextScreen))
```

Somewhat relatedly, using another initialiser, [you can also convert a `Binding<V?>` to a `Binding<V>?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297743/5133585) (answer by me).