# Exception when setting an optional binding to nil in SwiftUI after checking

Tags: exception, swiftui, option-type

I have a view with a `State` variable which is an `Optional`. I render the view by first checking if the optional variable is nil, and, if it is not, force unwrapping it and passing it into a subview using a `Binding`.

However, if I toggle the optional variable between a value and `nil`, the app crashes and I get a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` in the function `BindingOperations.ForceUnwrapping.get(base:)`. How can I get the expected functionality of the view simply displaying the 'Nil' `Text` view?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var optional: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if optional == nil {
                Text("Nil")
            } else {
                TestView(optional: Binding($optional)!)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                if optional == nil {
                    optional = 0
                } else {
                    optional = nil
                }
            }) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var optional: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(optional.description)
            
            Button(action: {
                optional += 1
            }) {
                Text("Increment")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that doesn't involve manually created bindings and/or hard-coded defaults. Here's a usage example:

```swift
if let unwrappedBinding = $optional.withUnwrappedValue {
  TestView(optional: unwrappedBinding)
} else {
  Text("Nil")
}
```

If you want, you could also provide a default value instead:

```swift
TestView(optional: $optional.defaulting(to: someNonOptional)
```

### Here are the extensions:

```swift
protocol OptionalType: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
  associatedtype Wrapped
  var optional: Wrapped? { get set }
}
extension Optional: OptionalType {
  var optional: Wrapped? {
    get { return self }
    mutating set { self = newValue }
  }
}

extension Binding where Value: OptionalType {
  /// Returns a binding with unwrapped (non-nil) value using the provided `defaultValue` fallback.
  var withUnwrappedValue: Binding<Value.Wrapped>? {
    guard let unwrappedValue = wrappedValue.optional else {
      return nil
    }
    
    return .init(get: { unwrappedValue }, set: { wrappedValue.optional = $0 })
  }

  /// Returns an optional binding with non-optional `wrappedValue` (`Binding<T?>` -> `Binding<T>?`).
  func defaulting(to defaultValue: Value.Wrapped) -> Binding<Value.Wrapped> {
    .init(get: { self.wrappedValue.optional ?? defaultValue }, set: { self.wrappedValue.optional = $0 })
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the withUnwrappedValue extension function. There is a built in Binding initializer that does it.

Comment: @Jonathan. try running the code in the original post - it crashes when the optional toggle switches to `nil`, even if you use the `Binding` init you're referring to, instead of force unwrapping. If you figure out a way to make that work, let me know.

Comment: Yep the built in initializer only replaces the withUnwrappedValue function, you still need the `defaulting(to:)` function. The original code has a force unwrap, so of course it will crash when it's set to to nil, as then the initializer with return nil for the Binding  which is then force unwrapped

Comment: @Jonathan. well what I was saying is that even if you refactor that code to use the `Binding.init?(_:)` and unwrap it with `if let`, it still crashes. I'm not sure why, because I would've assumed the built-in `init` is implemented roughly the same as what I wrote for `withUnwrappedValue`, but that doesn't seem to be the case, since it crashes even without force unwrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach to fix this. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

**The-Variant!** - Don't use optional state/binding & force-unwrap ever :)

*Variant1:* Use binding wrapper (no other changes)

```
CRTestView(optional: Binding(
        get: { self.optional ?? -1 }, set: {self.optional = $0}
    ))
```

*Variant2:* Transfer binding as-is

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var optional: Int?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if optional == nil {
                Text("Nil")
            } else {
                CRTestView(optional: $optional)
            }

            Button(action: {
                if optional == nil {
                    optional = 0
                } else {
                    optional = nil
                }
            }) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CRTestView: View {
    @Binding var optional: Int?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(optional?.description ?? "-1")

            Button(action: {
                optional? += 1
            }) {
                Text("Increment")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work in this example, however, in a larger app this would mean having to always check the optional which isn't ideal. The point of having the nil check is to avoid having an optional in the subview.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, I'm not going to mark it as the answer though because it seems like providing a default value after you have done a nil check is superfluous.