# Bridging Optional Binding to Non-Optional Child (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a parent state that *might* exist:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String? = nil
}
```

*If* that state exists, I want to show a child view. In this example, showing `name`.

If `name` is visible, I'd like it to be shown and editable. I'd like this to be two-way editable, that means if `Model.name` changes, I'd like it to push to the ChildUI, if the ChildUI edits this, I'd like it to reflect back to `Model.name`.

However, if `Model.name` becomes `nil`, I'd like `ChildUI` to hide.

When I do this, via unwrapping of the `Model.name`, then only the first value is captured by the `Child` who is now in control of that state. Subsequent changes will not push upstream because it is not a `Binding`.

**Question**

Can I have a non-optional upstream bind to an optional when it exists? (are these the right words?)

**Complete Example**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Child: View {
    // within Child, I'd like the value to be NonOptional
    @State var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("OK: ", text: $text).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    // within the parent, value is Optional
    @Published var name: String? = nil
}

struct Parent: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 12) {
            Text("Demo..")

            // whatever Child loads the first time will retain
            // even on change of model.name
            if let text = model.name {
                Child(text: text)
            }
            
            // proof that model.name changes are in fact updating other state
            Text("\(model.name ?? "<waiting>")")
        }
        .onAppear {
            model.name = "first change of optionality works"
            loop()
        }
    }
    
    @State var count = 0
    func loop() {
        async(after: 1) {
            count += 1
            model.name = "updated: \(count)"
            loop()
        }
    }
}

func async(_ queue: DispatchQueue = .main,
           after: TimeInterval,
           run work: @escaping () -> Void) {
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + after, execute: work)
}

struct OptionalEditingPreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Parent()
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm perhaps missing something about proper SwiftUI architecture, would appreciate also pointers to docs or architectures that cover this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Child` should take a `Binding` to the non-optional string, rather than using `@State`, because you want it to share state with its parent:

```
struct Child: View {
    // within Child, I'd like the value to be NonOptional
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("OK: ", text: $text).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
}
```

`Binding` has [an initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(_:)-5z9t9) that converts a `Binding<V?>` to `Binding<V>?`, which you can use like this:

```
            if let binding = Binding<String>($model.name) {
                Child(text: binding)
            }
```

If you're getting crashes from that, it's a bug in SwiftUI, but you can work around it like this:

```
            if let text = model.name {
                Child(text: Binding(
                    get: { model.name ?? text },
                    set: { model.name = $0 }
                ))
            }
```

Comment: thanks, rob, going to award this one since it has the original if let mostly maintained

Comment: heyoo, this will cause crashes if the binding is later set to `nil`, needs to wrap a binding for some reason like one of the things here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958106/exception-when-setting-an-optional-binding-to-nil-in-swiftui-after-checking

Comment: I've added a workaround you can try.

Comment: oh shoot yea I meant to tell you that was the workaround!

Comment: hey, just commenting here that there are some sort of weird quirks around this and for users to be careful. My current theory is that when we instantiate this way, outside of the swiftui context, it's no longer bound to the view and creates multiple binding instances. The bindings properly point back to `model.name`, but some views may disconnect from the binding chain and not receive updates which can occasionally manifest as strange behavior.

Comment: `if let binding = Binding($model.name)` — great solution for Optimal data type. Thank's Rob!

Answer (score 2):

Bind your var like this. Using custom binding and make your child view var `@Binding`.

```
struct Child: View {
    @Binding var text: String //<-== Here
   // Other Code
```

```
if model.name != nil {
   Child(text: Binding($model.name)!)
}
```

Comment: Swift has a better mechanism for dealing with unwrapping optionals: `if let`.

Comment: hey, noting here that this will create crashes if the value is set to `nil` elsewhere.. your original answer with the `get {} set` is correct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958106/exception-when-setting-an-optional-binding-to-nil-in-swiftui-after-checking

Comment: With Xcode 12.5.1 it's not crashing.

Comment: @RajaKishan it does crash if later set to nil, which is what Logan is referring to here.