# How to unwrap an Optional Binding and pass value to another view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've a `SwiftUI View` which requires a `Binding<Model>` for initialization. That model needs to be passed from a `List`, when user selects it. The selection parameter in a list initializer requires that model be optional, so the actual data type is `Binding<Model?>`.

Now how do I unwrap this optional and pass it to my `View`?

Here's how I tried to solve it by writing a simple wrapper view.

```
struct EditModelViewWrapper: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedModel: Model?
    @State var temperorayModel: Model = DataModel.placeholder
    
    init(selectedModel: Binding<Model?>) {
        self._selectedModel = selectedModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        if selectedModel == nil {
            Text("Kindly select a value in the list to start editing.")
        } else {
            EditModelView(model: boundModel)
        }
    }
    
    var boundModel: Binding<Model> {
        temperorayModel = $selectedModel.wrappedValue!
        return $temperorayModel
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following warning at the line, where I set value to `temperoryModel`.

> Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

PS: I don't want to pause an `Optional` to my `View` and check it inside for two reasons. It will require a lot of `nil` checks inside the view and I have to update a lot of other files in my app, where I have used that view.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297176/how-can-i-unwrap-an-optional-value-inside-a-binding-in-swift/58297743#58297743) help?

Comment: Yes. the problem is we are facing similar problems in different places in SwiftUI and each one understands the problem differently. Hence I was not able to search and find that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `boundModel` for such body, use instead

```
var body: some View {
    if selectedModel == nil {
        Text("Kindly select a value in the list to start editing.")
    } else {
        EditModelView(model: Binding(selectedModel)!)   // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: This crashes if selectedModel is later set to nil.