# unwrapping optional @State in SwiftUI when applied to a Binding

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm looking for a clean solution to resolve this SwiftUI challenge.

The following code compiles but do not work since `@State` property is outside the `ContentView` scope.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var state: LocalState?
  
  var body: some View {
    if let state = state {
      Toggle("Toggle", isOn: state.$isOn)
    }
  }
}

extension ContentView {
  struct LocalState {
    @State var isOn: Bool
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    VStack {
      ContentView(
        state: .init(isOn: false)
      )
      .border(Color.red)
      
      ContentView()
        .border(Color.red)
    }
    
  }
}
```

---

The following code doesn't compile since the following reasons:

> Value of optional type 'ContentView.LocalState?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'isOn' of wrapped base type 'ContentView.LocalState'

It seems that `$` in `$state.isOn` refer to the original `state` and not to the *unwrapped* one.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var state: LocalState!
  
  var body: some View {
    if let state = state {
      Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $state.isOn)
    }
  }
}

extension ContentView {
  struct LocalState {
    var isOn: Bool
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    VStack {
      ContentView(
        state: .init(isOn: false)
      )
      .border(Color.red)
      
      ContentView()
        .border(Color.red)
    }
  }
}
```

What I do NOT want is:

- use of failable initializer in ContentView.
- move `isOn` property outside `LocalState`.

How can I achieve those?

Comment: Just to be clear, what failable initialiser are you talking about here?

Comment: State wrapped variables can only exist at a View struct level. LocalState is not a valid place to put them in.

Comment: Optionals and SwiftUI wrappers are an uphill battle. I suggest giving LocalState an initial value or don’t show the view at all. Why have active toggles if local state doesn’t have a value?

Comment: Avoid implicit unwrapped optionals in Swift as much as possible and don't use them in SwiftUI at all. A `@State` is supposed to be owned be the current view and to have a default value (unless it's connected to something like a `selection`)

Comment: My intention is to have an empty body view in case I can't satisfy the initialization condition like init<T: GraphQLSelectionSet>(_ model: T?) where LocalState can't be defined due to possible nullity of the model).

Answer (score 6):

I believe this can be solved with two techniques. 1. using the Binding constructor that can create a non-optional binding from an optional. And 2. use of a constant binding in previews, e.g.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Config {
    var isOn: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var config: Config?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let config = Binding($config) { // technique 1
            ContentView2(config: config)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @Binding var config: Config
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $config.isOn)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView2(config: .constant(Config(isOn: false))) // technique 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you and @Sweeper for the idea, I just realized I can use two separate unwrap to achieve what I need.

Comment: I think u can replace ContentView2 with Toggle in ContentView. And think differently for Preview since constant make toggle not working.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var body: some View {
    if let isOn = Binding($state)?.isOn {
        Toggle("Toggle", isOn: isOn)
    }
}
```

Breaking it down: `$state` is a `Binding<LocalState?>`, and we use [the `Binding` initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/3115381-init) (hopefully that's not the failable initialiser that you don't want to use) to convert it to a `Binding<LocalState>?`. Then we can use optional chaining and `if let` to get a `Binding<Bool>` out of it.

Related: [How can I unwrap an optional value inside a binding in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58297176/5133585)

Comment: This is nice solution, a @State init which accept optional values and let unwrap would be awesome, not sure is that possible.

Answer (score -1):

`$state` is syntactic sugar for `_state.projectedValue`, which gives you a `Binding<LocalState?>`. And from here on things are ugly.

You might be able to get away with a wrapped binding:

```
var wrappedIsOn: Binding<Bool> {
    let stateBinding = $state
    return Binding {
        stateBinding.wrappedValue?.isOn ?? false
    } set: {
        stateBinding.wrappedValue?.isOn = $0
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Toggle("Toggle", isOn: wrappedIsOn)
```

And alternative, inspired by @Sweeper's answer:

```
Toggle("Toggle", isOn: Binding($state)?.isOn ?? Binding.constant(false))
```