# How do I downcast and get a binding at the same time?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var vehicle: any Vehicle
}
```

then in the view

```
var body : some View {
   if let truck = vm.vehicle as? Truck {
           TextField("Name", text: $vm.truck.name)    // how to write this so it compiles?
   }
}
```

name is a property of Truck, but not Vehicle. What I'm trying to do, is if it's castable to a truck then show this textfield, otherwise don't show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new `Truck?` property in `vm`, that returns non-nil if `vehicle` is `Truck`:

```
var truck: Truck? {
    get { vehicle as? Truck }
    set {
        if let value = newValue {
            vehicle = value
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use the `Binding` initialiser that turns a `Binding<T?>` into a `Binding<T>?` (see also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297743/5133585))

```
if let binding = Binding($vm.truck) {
    TextField("Foo", text: binding.name)
}
```

Alternatively, make your own `Binding` with the `init(get:set:)` initialiser.

```
extension Binding {
    init?<V>(_ binding: Binding<V>) {
        let optionalBinding = Binding<Value?>(get: { binding.wrappedValue as? Value }, set: {
            if let v = $0 as? V {
                binding.wrappedValue = v
            }
        })
        if let new = Binding(optionalBinding) {
            self = new
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

```
if let binding = Binding<Truck>($vm.vehicle) {
    TextField("Foo", text: binding.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this approach:

```
if var truck = vm.vehicle as? Truck {
    TextField("Name", text: Binding(
        get: { truck.name },
        set: { truck.name = $0 })
    )
    .onSubmit {
        vm.vehicle = truck
    }
}
```