# Initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' requires that optional array conform to 'MutableCollection' AND 'RandomAccessCollection'

Tags: swiftui

I have a view model like so:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let myService: MyServiceProtocol

    @Published var days: [Day]?

    ...
}
```

Then, in a view, I have the following:

```
struct TripDayView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        if let days = $myViewModel.days {
            ForEach(days, id: \.id) { $day in
                CustomView(day: $day)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my CustomView, I take `day` as a @Binding:

```
struct CustomView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    
    @Binding var day: Day

    ...
}
```

But on the line with `ForEach` I'm getting these two errors:

> Initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' requires that '[Day]?' conform to 'MutableCollection'
>
> Initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' requires that '[Day]?' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'

What does this mean and how do I fix this?

Comment: Does `@Published var days: [Day]?` _have to_ be `Optional`? Can you just use an empty array instead? If so, the fix becomes trivial

Comment: @jnpdx I suppose it doesn't have to be Optional. And is passing `Day` as a @Binding the "right" way of doing things in SwiftUI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I unwrap an optional value inside a binding in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297176/how-can-i-unwrap-an-optional-value-inside-a-binding-in-swift)

Comment: @user2343632 If you need a `Binding`, then, yes, it is one of the "right" ways

Comment: `if let days = $myViewModel.days` requires `$myViewModel.days` to be of an optional type, but it isn't. Its type is `Binding<[Day]?>` . You can convert this to the optional type `Binding<[Day]>?`, using the `Binding` initialiser shown in the dupe target.

Comment: IMO the deleted solution is much better: re-creating Binding every time is an ugly hack, not a solution.

Comment: @timbretimbre Why is it an ugly hack? `$myViewModel.days` "creates a binding every time" too. When do you think that `Binding` initialiser should be used then?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct TripDayView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        if let days = myViewModel.days {
            ForEach(days, id: \.id) { day in
                CustomView(day: .constant(day))
            }
        }
    }
}
```