# Can't pass object as Binding to child view from within a loop

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a class which holds a list of `Trip`s. I want to use this as the single source of truth for the user's trips through the app:

```
class TripManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var trips = [Trip]()
}
```

And this is what the `Trip` model looks like:

```
struct Trip: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var unorganizedStops: [TripStop]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case unorganizedStops = "unorganized_stops"
    }
}
```

In my main home view, I loop through the user's trips and display them each as a `TripItem`. I pass the trip as a binding:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var tripManager: TripManager
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach($tripManager.trips, id: \.id) { $trip in
                TripItem(trip: $trip)
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(tripManager)
    }
}
```

Inside `TripItem`, I have it such that when the user taps on the item, they are navigated to the `TripPageView`, again passing trip as a binding:

```
struct TripItem: View {
    @Binding var trip: Trip
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: TripPageView(trip: $trip)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In `TripPageView`, I pass the trip as a binding to `StopsView`, but here is where I'm stuck.

```
struct TripPageView: View {
    @Binding var trip: Trip
    @EnvironmentObject var tripManager: TripManager
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollViewReader { value in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        StopsView(trip: $trip)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(tripManager)
    }
}

struct StopsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var tripManager: TripManager
    @Binding var trip: Trip
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            if (!(trip.unorganizedStops ?? []).isEmpty) {
                let stops = trip.unorganizedStops
                
                VStack {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(stops ?? [], id: \.id) { stop in
                            StopView(stop: stop)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`StopView` expects `TripStop` to be passed as binding. But I'm not really sure how to do that here. I am receiving the error `Cannot convert value of type 'TripStop' to expected argument type 'Binding<TripStop>'` on the line `StopView(stop: stop)`.

I've tried several different things but nothing is working.

How do I fix this?

Am I using EnvironmentObjects and Bindings wrong?

Comment: You already know how to get a binding from a `ForrEach`. In `HomeView`, you wrote `ForEach($tripManager.trips, id: \.id) { $trip in ... }`. Just do that here too - pass a `Binding<[TripStop]>` into the `ForEach`. `$trip.unorganizedStops` gives you a `Binding<[TripStop]?>`, and you can convert that to a `Binding<[TripStop]>?` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297743/5133585), then just unwrap the optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways and workarounds to `force` an optional binding in the `ForEach` loop,
but instead I suggest an alternative with a minor modification of your code,
making your `unorganizedStops` not optional.

Try this approach using a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` for
decoding your `Trip`.

```
struct Trip: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var unorganizedStops: [TripStop] // <-- here
    
    init(id: Int, unorganizedStops: [TripStop]) {
        self.id = id
        self.unorganizedStops = unorganizedStops
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case unorganizedStops = "unorganized_stops"
    }
    
    // -- here
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        if let temp = try container.decodeIfPresent([TripStop].self, forKey: .unorganizedStops) {
            self.unorganizedStops = temp
        } else {
            self.unorganizedStops = []
        }
    }
}

// for testing
struct TripStop: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
    //....
}

struct StopsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var tripManager: TripManager
    @Binding var trip: Trip

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    ForEach($trip.unorganizedStops) { $stop in
                        StopView(stop: $stop)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// for testing
struct StopView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var tripManager: TripManager
    @Binding var stop: TripStop
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $stop.name).border(.red)
    }
}
```

Wherever you had in your code `if trip.unorganizedStops == nil {...}` use `if trip.unorganizedStops.isEmpty {...}`.
Everwhere else using a non optional `trip.unorganizedStops` makes coding a lot simpler.